# Подгрузка товаров при клике, woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

На странице магазина `/shop` выводится список всех товаров.
Как сделать, чтобы выводилось сначала определённое количество товаров, допустим 4, и ниже будет кнопка "Загрузить", по клику которой должны загрузиться следующие 4 товара?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте плагин [Load More Products for WooCommerce](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/load-more-products-for-woocommerce/)

Comment: этот плагин подходит, который вы посоветовали. Подскажите ещё пожалуйста, на сайте используется также плагин WC Ajax Product Filter https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wc-ajax-product-filter/, т.е. на странице` /shop` работают эти два плагина: слева выводятся фильтры, а справа выводятся товары и под ними кнопка для загрузки следующих товаров. Но если выбрать какой-то фильтр, то этот фильтр не применяется для кнопке `load more product`. Как можно эти два плагина подружить, т.е. чтобы настройки фильтров влияли на подгружаемые товары?

Comment: тут наверно проще будет сделать самому кнопку для загрузки товаров, чтобы данная кнопка работала с плагином фильтров.
Подскажите, как можно реализовать такое, чтобы страницы /shop/page/numpage можно было заменить на загрузку с помощью ajax?